# how to access elastic beanstalk app after linking it to godaddy domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, godaddy-api

I have created a spring boot application and deployed it to AWS elastic beanstalk. I could easily access it with the environment URL provided by AWS. Then I implemented SSL in my app. I tested it locally and it was responding on https request but not on http request. Then I got a domain from godaddy and I linked it to my AWS elastic beanstalk app by following AWS route 53 documentation carefully. How can I access my spring boot app now? None of these CNAME, Alias or any other record set URL is working
[These are the record sets I have created and linked to my elastic beanstalk app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fS8F.png)

Comment: Is your EB environment single-instance type or load-balanced?

Comment: single instance

Comment: So everything works, except when you try accessing the site using custom domain name? Usually it takes some time for dns entries to propagate. Also make sure to clear up all browser caches.

Answer (score 0):

You should only need an "A" record type here that directs www..com to your EB url and then one name server "NS" record where you'll enter the detail retrieved from your GoDaddy account in "My Domains" > "Select Domain" > "Domain Settings".

One record for NS and the "value" portion will be the 4 name servers you found in GoDaddy.